# AM/PM in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I need the time in AM/PM format in an [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) 3 application, and I am using the following statement:

```
@Model.ReportDate.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

But it is returning 6:45 instead of 6:45 PM. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ttSpecifier) are culture/locale dependent so it may be using the settings from your server (e.g. 24 hour time). Try this:

```
@Model.ReportDate.ToString("hh:mm tt", 
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If this (or something similar) solves your problem, I suggest setting the desired culture in `global.asax` so your entire app uses the culture you expect.

Answer (score 0):

[Depends on the culture:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

> For cultures that do not use an AM (or PM)
>   designator, this property returns an
>   empty string.

try to use the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

```
ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
```

It is associated with the English language but not with any country/region.